# Run AD search for users not in Group excluding OU's

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Good Afternoon

I am trying to create a PS script which pulls all users not in a certain Security group. I have managed to get this to work fine. However i require it to omit certain OU's as i don't want certain accounts included in this process like terminated users and support accounts for examples.

So i created the below to do this but it seems to fail. Its where i have tried to add some filtering. Can someone help put this in the right direction?

```
import-Module activedirectory
$results = @()
$users = Get-ADUser  -Properties memberof -Filter {enabled -eq $true} | ? {$_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*,OU=Exchange,OU=Support Accounts,OU=Terminated Users and Computers do not use,OU=TerminatedEmployeesContractors,OU=TestAccounts*"} * 
$ExportPath = 'c:\app\users_in_ou1.csv'
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $groups = $user.memberof -join ';'
    $results += New-Object psObject -Property @{'User'=$user.name;'Groups'= $groups}
    }
$results | Where-Object { $_.groups -notmatch 'SG_XXXXXXXXXXX' } | Select-Object user | export-csv $ExportPath
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build a regex from all OUs that should be excluded from the search by joining the strings with the regex 'OR' character (`|`) and use the `-notmatch` operator.
 Because there may be characters in these strings that have special meaning in regex, use `[Regex]::Escape()` on each before joining them.

Something like below:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# create a regex from an array of OUs to exclude by 'OR-ing' them with the pipe character
$excludeOUs = ('OU=Exchange','OU=Support Accounts','OU=Terminated Users and Computers do not use',
               'OU=TerminatedEmployeesContractors','OU=TestAccounts' | ForEach-Object {[Regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'

$ExportPath = 'c:\app\users_in_ou1.csv'

# get a list of objects not having any of the excluded OUs in their DistinguishedName
# and at the same time output objects with properties 'User' and 'Groups'
$users = Get-ADUser -Properties Name, MemberOf -Filter 'Enabled -eq $true' | 
              Where-Object {$_.DistinguishedName -notmatch $excludeOUs} |
              Select-Object @{Name = 'User'; Expression = {$_.Name}},
                            @{Name = 'Groups'; Expression = {($_.MemberOf -join ';')}}

# next filter this out further by excluding a certain group and export to Csv
$users | Where-Object { $_.Groups -notmatch 'SG_XXXXXXXXXXX' } | Export-Csv $ExportPath -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. So in theory i can also add more OU's to the exclusion. It will pull from the top OU down.

Comment: THis worked a treat as well. Thank you for the input appreciate it.